# react-native-maps-super-cluster : How to make multiple type of clusters

Tags: react-native-maps, react-native-map-clustering

I have managed to make clusters with react-native-maps-super-cluster . My requirement is now to create multiple clusters based on the cluster points category. For example , if i have 10 markers , 5 being one type and the remaining another type. I need 2 clusters with the marers grouped in to two.